# I have ext2 formatted file system Images. I like to read in terminal all the file system structures data in Linux specifically Ubuntu.Is there a tool>

Tags: linux, image, filesystems, ext2, diskimage

So I have file system ext2 formatted image files. I like to view Inode, super block, filenames, etc. in the images for formatted file systsem . I like to know is there any tool for this. I need to view these structures like inode, superblock, file, related info like names of files, deleted inodes etc. In terminal, posssible some tool with available code in Linux. So can be editted the tool. Would be best if tool is coded in just C languange. Can anyone please do tell me this, Thanks again. Just opensource tool

Comment: I tried gimp, Its graphical I dont want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I understood your question, but I think you probably just want to *"loopback mount"* your filesystem in a file. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device).

Failing that, I think you can use `e2tools` to access the contents. See [here](https://github.com/e2tools/e2tools).

Comment: I need to compile this source of e2tools do u know how this can be done and then install and reinstall https://github.com/e2tools/e2tools

Comment: I've never done that, but I think this is the approach... https://github.com/e2tools/e2tools/blob/master/INSTALL.from-git

Comment: Ok its working now. Can u also please give little bit info on the layouts of structures in EXT2 formated image files, I believe super block starts at offset 0. So if I cast like `char *..=(struct ext2_sb_info *)ext2_image_file_data` will give me superblock and there is only one superblock in a filesystem for ext2 file system. Is this correct. I also need to read inodes and file infos. can u please tell me this?

Comment: Sorry, I am no expert on filesystem layouts.